# MissingResourceException after updating from Laravel 7 to 9 and php 7 to 8

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

I recently upgraded a Laravel 7 application to 9 and then upgraded php to version 8.1
The application also uses Laravel Nova and it uses the Currency field extensively. It also uses `Symfony\Component\Intl\Currencies;` quite extensively.

On my development machine (macOS) the application works fine.

The application is deployed as a serverless application via Laravel Vapor. When I try to run it, I get the following error

```
Symfony\Component\Intl\Exception\MissingResourceException: Couldn't read the indices [Names][][0] for the locale "en" in "/var/task/vendor/symfony/intl/Resources/data/currencies". The indices also couldn't be found for the fallback locale(s) "root".
Location
vendor/symfony/intl/Data/Bundle/Reader/BundleEntryReader.php:175 - Symfony\Component\Intl\Data\Bundle\Reader\BundleEntryReader::readEntry
```

Following several hours of research, I have tried adding the following to composer

```
    "ext-intl": "*",
    "symfony/intl": "^6.0"
```

This does not appear to solve the problem and I'm a bit stumped. Does anyone have any ideas, is there something I should be installing globally for this to work correctly? Any advice would be most welcome.

**UPDATE**
I though to mention, I'm using this docker image: laravelphp/vapor:php81